# Why is sklearn's TfidfVectorizer returning an empty matrix when I pass an argument for vocabulary, but not when I don't?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to get the tf-idf for a set of documents using the following code:

```
documents = ['iADV díltudNOUN iADV gaibidVERB gabálNOUN', 'iADV díthNOUN dérnumNOUN iADP foileNOUN', ...]
vocab = ['aADP', 'aDET', 'aPRON', 'achtSCONJ', 'amalSCONJ', 'arADP', 'arPRON', ...]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r"(?u)\b[\wáéíóúↄḟṁṅæǽ⁊ɫ֊̃]+\b", vocabulary=vocab)
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
print(vectors)
```

When I do this the matrix is empty. If I try to `print([vectors])` instead, I can see the shape of the matrix, but there is no data in it.

```
[<42x79 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

Weirdly, when I remove the `vocabulary=vocab` argument, I can get the tf-idf for all of the words in the documents, though, I really don't want it for all words:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r"(?u)\b[\wáéíóúↄḟṁṅæǽ⁊ɫ֊̃]+\b")
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
print(vectors)

  (0, 564)  0.09058331497564333
  (0, 313)  0.09058331497564333
  (0, 93)   0.08155482537999634
  (0, 165)  0.06268804803234075
  (0, 169)  0.09058331497564333
  ...
```

What is causing my matrix to be empty when I pass the `vocabulary` argument? Is there something wrong with my `token_pattern`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the default parameter `lowercase` which is equal to `True`. So, all your text is tranformed in lowercase. If you change your vocabulary to lowercase, it will work :

```
vocab=[v.lower() for v in vocab]
```

You can also change the paramater `lowercase` to `False`